# User tagging auto linking - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app. I am trying to write a helper that `auto_links` the mention of a `"@someusername"` in a comment and link to `user_path("@someusername")`.

How can I do this?

Can I just customize the `auto_link` helper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems pretty easy to do.

```
def auto_link_usernames(text)
  text.gsub /@(\w+)/ do |username|
    link_to(username, user_username_path(username.gstub('@', '')))
  end.html_safe
end
```

You need to add a new route and controller action so you can have user pages with usernames like `/user/:username`

In your controller you would do

```
def username_show
  @user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
  render 'show'
end
```

Edit:

Actually this works perfectly:

```
def auto_link_usernames(text)
  text.gsub /@(\w+)/ do |username|
    link_to(username, user_path(username.gsub('@', '')))
  end.html_safe
end
```

Comment: But who will call this method? `auto_link` specifically calls the methods `auto_link_email_addresses` and so on, so you can't just add another method and be done with it.

Comment: This just substitutes @someusername to /users/@someusername in the comment body and links to the same page not the user's page

Comment: I have a few quick questions, can you please jump in this chat box thingy: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48735/rails-user-tag-helper

Answer (score 2):

This one works better, \b is word break detection, so the sentence could be just @username and nothing else, and it will still work (white space and , are also considered as word break).

```
def auto_link_usernames(text)
  text.gsub /(?<=\s|^)@[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\b)/ do |username|
  link_to(username, user_path(username.gsub('@', '')))
  end.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [gem in which auto_link has been extracted from Rails 3.1+](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink/blob/master/lib/rails_autolink/helpers.rb), it appears that they didn't think of auto_link as being extensible. [Line 64](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink/blob/master/lib/rails_autolink/helpers.rb#L64) shows a case statement where they call methods specific to each type of autolinking, so you'll have to add your new method here if you want it to be picked up.

If I were you, I would fork this gem from Github and modify it's source. This presumes you're using Rails 3.1+. You can even submit a pull request to the gem maintainers to see if they want to add in this functionality.

If you're not using the gem or don't want to fork a git repo, I suppose I would monkey-patch it like this: I would create my own helper, called `ReferenceAutolink` or some such, make it extend `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`, and place it in your app's helpers as you would any other helper. I'm pretty sure that application helpers can override existing helpers when you call `helper_method`, so I would simply copy and paste the existing auto-link code into this helper and add another method to delegate to in the case statement which handles your referencing links. You'll have to rewrite the whole case statement, because it appears they cascade method calls in order to determine precedence.

It's a bit gross, but doable.